# Store data temporarily in a multiple activity app till the app is stopped?

Tags: java, android

I have a RecyclerView (recycler1) which shows a list of users in my first activity. When you click on any item, a new activity is opened where you can chat with that user. The messages are shown yet in another RecyclerView (recycler2). But on clicking the back button, my recyclerview becomes empty. How can I store the messages for some time such that when I click on any users, the messages that I had with him while my app was active is shown? And I want the saved messages to be deleted if I kill my app i.e closed it completely?

Answer (score -1):

Set up a class with fields and getters/setters for all the information you will need for your messages. Every time you start an activity, pass an instance of that class with all the fields filled out through the parameters. The java heap will remove all traces of the memory once the app closes.

```
public class MessageData {
private ArrayList<String> messages;
public void addMessages(String message) {
//Acts as a setter
messages.add(message);
}
public ArrayList<String> getMessages() {
return messages;
}
}
```

Comment: I have the class which will store the sender name and the message. But I am unable to get the specific  messagelist related to the user that I am clicking. Can you provide me with some example code.

Comment: Check it out now.